# Apache: return 404 errors instead of 500 errors

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, error-reporting

In apache I'd like to return 404 errors whenever I get a 500 error.

Its a very strange use case, I know, but I'm wondering if its possible.

I found this

http://www.4webhelp.net/tutorials/misc/errors.php

Which leads me to believe you can change what happens on the different errors.  Something like this would be great

ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/error404.cgi

ErrorDocument 500 /cgi-bin/error404.cgi

As suggested by the article, but I don't seem to have error404.cgi on my Ubuntu installation.  Any idea where I can get it, or an alternative solution?

Comment: ErrorDocument directives change the message that is displayed to the user, but they do not affect the status code that the server reports behind the scenes to the browser.

Do you just want to hide the "500 Error" message from the user (in which case this would suffice), or do you in fact want to entirely prevent the server from reporting a 500 to the browser, regardless of what the user sees?

Comment: I'm looking to do this as well, whether it's with `ErrorDocument` or some other Apache solution

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your question but are you sure that you really want to do this? a 500 error and 404 are very different things meant to be used for different purposes.  You are telling a user that the url that they have is wrong when in fact it is what is more than likely a temporary problem with your application/server.  Why would you rather do this than to tell the user there is a temporary problem and they should try again later on? Or in other words, why not just have a custom 500 error page?

Comment: Yeah, its basically a very temporary solution.  Its an error that I don't have the power to fix on some old code.  New code will replace it in a month, but in the mean time I need a certain set of pages that are currently reporting 500 errors to return 404s.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create error404.cgi. Go to /usr/lib/cgi-bin and then create a file called error404.cgi it should be either Perl (default) or if Python is enabled, you can use either. If you do not know either Python or Perl, heres a basic Perl script which should work for you: (You can download the script from my website at cwarren.uuuq.com/downloads/perl/404.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
print "<html>";
print "<head>";
print "<title>404 ERROR!</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print "<h1>Sorry for the broken link, but this page is not here!</h1>";
print "<br><br>";
print "<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">Click here to go back to the previous page.</a>";
exit(0);
```

Another option would be to change the link to /var/www/404.html or something.

Comment: Two issues here: First, there's no reason that this needs to be a CGI script. The target of an ErrorDocument directive can be any file on the webserver, including just plain HTML. Second: while this will *say* "404 Error" to the user, it's still going to return an HTTP status code of 500 to the web browser when used as the ErrorDocument for a 500-error.

Comment: Yeah, I need a 400 error returned to the browser, not just a different page returned to the user.  

Thanks for the try.